# How to Fine-tuning a Pretrained Network in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Can anyone give an example of how to fine tune a pretrained imagenet network with new data and different classes similar to this:

[Fine-tuning a Pretrained Network for Style Recognition](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/examples/03-fine-tuning.ipynb)

Answer (score 1):

This [TensorFlow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining) describes how to retrain a image classifier for new data and new classes.